# After a successful AJAX call cant update td data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks For viewing this post.i am facing a jquery issue .After a successful AJAX call, I want to update an element on page. However, it is not being updated.

what am i doing i am opening a text box on click of span then add text and  and on focus out event i am making Ajax call but cant update new text to same span when that i clicked before please help me

here is my js code

```
$(document).on('click', '.td-edit', (function (e0) {
    var thisObj = $(this);
    var olddata = thisObj.html();
    var newDom = '<input type="text" value="' + olddata + '"  class="new-value" style="border:#bbb 1px solid;padding-left:5px;width:75%;"/ >';
    thisObj.parent('td').html(newDom);
}));
$(document).on('focusout', '.new-value', (function (e1) {
    var thisObj = $(this);
    var type = thisObj.parent('td').attr('class');
    var newData = thisObj.val();
    var santanceId = thisObj.parent('td').parent('tr').attr('id');
    santanceId = parseInt(santanceId.replace('tr', ''));
    thisObj.parent('td').html('\'<img src="uploads/loading.gif">\'');
    if (type === 'sentnc') {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "operations.php",
            data: {
                santanceId: santanceId,
                sentnc: newData
            },
            success: function () {
                var newDom = '<span class="td-edit">' + newData + '</span>';
                thisObj.parent('td').html(newDom);
            }
        });

    }
}));
```

HTML:

```
<div class="chat-space nano nscroller">
  <div id="table-row">
    <table id="rep-data">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th align="left">Sentences</th>
          <th align="left" colspan="3">Reps</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="tr1" rowspan="2">
          <td class="sentnc"><span class="td-edit">Rana is working</span></td>
          <td colspan="3" class="senrep"><span class="td-edit">p1.ref = I, p1.name = julie</span><br>
            <br>
            <span style="color:#000;">Guess Rep1:&nbsp;</span><span id="1gr1">p1.ref = I, p1.has = name1, p1.name.made_from = rana</span><br>
            <span style="color:#000;">Guess Rep2:&nbsp;</span><span id="2gr1">p1.ref = I, p1.name = rana</span><br>
            <span><a style="color:#3399FF !important;" alt="1" rel="1 " class="updateGuess" id="upd1" href="javascript:void(0);">Update Guess Rep</a></span><br>
            <br></td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: You are not using the results of your ajax call.  If that's your intent, I'm not sure why you're even making the ajax call.  If you intend to use the results of the ajax call, then you need to declare an argument to the `success` handler and use that argument to get access to the results of the ajax call.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes i am not using ajax response data i made ajax call just to update content into my database

Comment: http://s30.postimg.org/me70rqn29/Firefox_Screenshot_2014_03_22_T03_59_03_464_Z.png i am clicking on rana is working then textbox open and again on focusout event i am making ajax call after this i cant update the parent td

Comment: jQuery is so awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Your `success` handler should be:

```
success: function (data) {
                var newDom = '<span class="td-edit">' + data + '</span>';
                thisObj.parent('td').html(newDom);
            }
```

Here, the `data` is the data returned by your server, after the ajax Call

Comment: newdata is a data that i entered in text box thisObj cant find parent

Comment: where is `.new-value`? and what is it?

Comment: provide some html so that i could help u